# Ring homomorphisms from $C[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ all of certain form

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

> Let $R$ be the ring of real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1].$ Note that if $0 \le t \le 1$ then  the evaluation map $\psi_t :f \mapsto f(t)$ is a homomorphism of $R$ into $\Bbb R$. Show that any homomorphism $\varphi$ of $R$ into $\Bbb R$ is of this form.

Let $\varphi : R \to \Bbb R$ be a homomorphism such that $\varphi \ne \psi_t$ for any $t \in [0,1]$. This means that for all $t$ there exists $f \in R$ such that $\varphi(f) \ne \psi_t(f)=f(t)$.

I'm trying to show that $\varphi$ cannot be a homomorphism unless it's of the form $\psi_t$, but I don't know how to argue from here. I'm told to consider something called a partition of unity, but I haven't heard of these beforehand and don't really now how to use them here. Is there another way to proceed?

Comment: The kernel of the homomorphism would have to be a maximal ideal.  The question about the maximal ideals of $C[0,1]$ is asked very frequently and has many solutions on the site.

Comment: Why would it need to be maximal? I don't think the kernels are maximal ideals neccessarily. @rschwieb

Comment: when the image is a field, then kernel is maximal, because $R/K\cong \mathbb R$.  The ideals of the field correspond with the ideals of the quotient. All two of them.

Comment: That I know, but there is no guarantee that for an arbitary homomorphism $\varphi$ we have that $\text{Im}(\varphi)$ is a field. There is no mention that $\varphi$ should be surjective. @rschwieb

Comment: *there is no guarantee that...* Yes, that is true.  *There is no mention that...* No explicit mention, but nevertheless, the evaluation map **is** surjective.  I'm pretty sure "of this form" is meant to be "a ring homomorphism onto $\mathbb R$."

Comment: It's also not that hard to show that any such ring homomorphisms is surjective.

Comment: I think we're talking about different things here. The evaluation map certainly is surjective so for $\varphi$ a evaluation map $R/\ker(\varphi) \cong \Bbb R$. And since $\Bbb R$ is a field $\ker(\varphi)$ is maximal and thus of the form $M_c = \{ f \in R \mid f(c) = 0\}$ for $c \in [0,1]$. But I'm not talking about evaluation maps. What I'm trying to show is that if I pick any homomorphism (not neccessarily an evaluation map), then I'll arrive at a contradiction if it's not an evaluation map. I understood from your comment that even this kind of homomorphism should give a maximal kernel?

Comment: @rschwieb I think I need to mention you in order for you to get a notification.

Comment: @SleepWalker This [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159801/characterizing-all-ring-homomorphisms-c0-1-to-mathbbr) seems like a good starting point for that.